# django project sheme in form of tree in git bash

Tags: django, git

I'm creating my first django app and I want to ask what command in git bash can
show structure of my project in form like at the underneath.

Thanks for help

```
    Include/
man/
Procfile/
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
Scripts/
tcl/
webadvisorapi
    │   manage.py
    ├───src
    │   │   admin.py
    │   │   apps.py
    │   │   models.py
    │   │   serializers.py
    │   │   tests.py
    │   │   urls.py
    │   │   views.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   ├───scripts
    │           request.py
    │           __init__.py
    │
    ├───static
    │       .keep
    │
    ├───staticfiles
    └───webadvisorapi
        │   settings.py
        │   urls.py
        │   wsgi.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        ├───static
        │       .keep
```

Comment: It can't. `git` can show you the graph/tree of your commits, but it won't do it for your files in your project (unlike the `tree` command)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, `git` cannot do such a thing. Both UNIX and Windows systems should have a command `tree` that does exactly what you want.